# Where are the proprietary NVIDIA drivers in 16.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, proprietary

The *proprietary* NVIDIA drivers "disappeared" with my latest update:

[image]

The option of "Proprietary drivers for devices" is correctly set under the "Ubuntu Software" tab. I have the graphics-driver PPA (**ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa**) correctly added to my sources.

Any ideas on how to bring the proprietary drivers back?

PS1: I need them because some of the games I play under wine don't work without them, for whatever reason.

PS2: Also, this feels like it should have a straightforward answer, but I've been looking online for a while without luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All these drivers, except `X.Org` are proprietary Nvidia drivers.

The `open source` is a bug of the user interface.

In your case the proprietary driver is already installed.

Comment: oh wow, that's confusing. So there are no NVIDIA open soruce packages?

Comment: That is correct. Open source drivers are installed by default. Part of them is in kernel, part in `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`. There is nothing to install.